# "itmstransporter" permission error when publishing iBook

Tags: permission, books, ibooks-author, itunes-producer

I've created a book using iBooks Author, sent it over to iTunes Producer, filled in all of the necessary details (price, availability, etc) and attempted to submit it.  Once I submit it to Apple I see it successfully authenticate with Apple but then I receive the following three errors:

> Unable to write to configuration directory: /Users/jdoe/.itmstransporter
>
> Your home folder must be writable in order to save run-time configuration data.  Please ensure your home folder exists and is writable.
>
> Cannot save local copy of remote diagnostic configuration; local path is not writable

I've verified that my home directory (/Users/jdoe/) does exist, it's permissions are set so that jdoe can read & write and staff & system both have read permission.

I've restarted my Mac & repaired disk permissions using Disk Utility but the issue has persisted.  Mid 2012 Mac Pro, 10.9.3, approximately 460GB free on the system volume, where /Users/jdoe resides.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525538/app-failing-validation-unable-to-create-configuration-directory-user-username

Comment: @Rob - I meant to mention that, I found that question/answer while searching for info.  The error message is the same but the same fix doesn't apply to my situation.

Comment: @Buscar웃 - I had already tried that but with no success, I've edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: Disk Utility will not fix your home folder, I recommend a cappuccino and this (fix your ACLs) https://discussions.apple.com/message/23287257#23287257 by LincDavis